# Узнать ширину блока по длине строки

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Есть такая задача:
Необходимо по длине строки узнать ширину блока.

Более подробно:

есть несколько блоков div с **overflow-x: auto**; и **overflow-y: hidden;**. В каждом таком диве есть элемент **p**. Ширина **div**'a = **100%;**

Необходимо узнать ширину элемента **p** и если она больше чем **$(window).width()- 94**, добавить к элементу содержащемуся в родительском блоке некий класс.

Если выводить alert'ом, то получается странная ситуация - элемент **p** всегда меньше, чем window.width().

**Как не задавая явно ширину блока, задать ее исходя из длинны строки, чтобы только те элементы у которых длинна строки больше window.width() имели полосу прокрутки и можно было для их братских элементов задать какой-либо класс?**

Для удобства - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/dVdtE/

Спасибо.

Comment: невозможно зная длину строки символов, без создания соответствующего DOM элемента, вычислить длину элементов ее содержащих, кроме как для monospace шрифтов.

Comment: @eicto, a если с созданием DOM элемента, то как?

Comment: но, возможно, вы хотите [этого](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/dVdtE/1/)

Comment: @Astor примерно, как показал @Sh4dow, только без alert() в цикле :)

Comment: Да, возможно, но теперь самое интересное: как вычислить, что текст выходит за пределы экрана и задать класс определенному элементу ...?

Comment: @eicto, да, именно этого. Большое, нет, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так ?

CSS:

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

JS:

```
var wWidth=$(window).width()-94;
$('p').each(function(){
    var $this=$(this);    
    $this.addClass('test');
    var w=$(this).width();
    $this.removeClass('test');
    if (w>wWidth) $this.addClass('red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/dVdtE/4/

Comment: ну или [так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/dVdtE/5/) ?

Comment: @eicto, чет я торможу ... вроде все правильно и должно работать, но нет ... 

Вот более полный код - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/Qw2Kc/

Необходимо в созданный с помощью js элемент добавить класс - .item-icon-shadow

Вроде бы и прописал по аналогии, а все равно не работает.

Comment: а где у вас добавление тестового класса ? и сам класс ?

Comment: Класс прописан в CSS .item-icon-shadow

Comment: тоже прописан в CSS - .about-user li span.item-icon

Именно к нему необходимо добавить класс с тенью.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/Qw2Kc/1/

Но теперь полоса прокрутки появляется у всего окна - чего быть не должно. Полоса прокрутки должна быть только у li div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/J55Vz/ вы этого хотите ?

Answer (score 3):

По фидлу:

css

```
div p.test {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

js

```
var n = 1;
$('div p').addClass('test').each(function() {
  var w = $(this).width(),
      o = w > $(window).width()- 94;
    alert(n+++': '+w+(o ? ' overflow!' : ''));
}).removeClass('test');
```

text

Меняем элементу стиль так, чтобы он игнорировал ширину окна, считаем, меняем стиль обратно. Думаю, должно хватить.

Comment: @Sh4dow, спасибо, но это не совсем то о чем я спрашивал ...